# Updating column value and deleting row in R

Tags: r

I am reading csv file and trying to update value of column named 'added' based on condition when bug_id and bug_when of two consecutive rows are same and added column of ith row has value "RESOLVED" then value of added column on (i+1) row updated by concatenating values of 'added' column (i and i + 1 rows) and delete the ith row. I tired but it didn't work properly.  The file contains the following information:

```
bug_id  bug_when            field       added
1141327 2015-03-09 16:21:30 Status      RESOLVED
1141327 2015-03-09 16:21:30 Resolution  DUPLICATE
1142623 2015-03-24 18:15:22 Status      RESOLVED
1142623 2015-03-24 18:15:22 Resolution  FIXED
1143179 2015-07-30 09:37:56 Status      RESOLVED
1143179 2015-07-30 09:37:56 Resolution  FIXED
```

Here is my code:

```
dataframe <- read.csv("prototype.csv", header = TRUE)
start <- 1
end <- nrow(dataframe)-1

for(i in start:end)
{
  if(dataframe$bug_id[i]==dataframe$bug_id[i+1] & dataframe$bug_when[i]==dataframe$bug_when[i+1])
  {
    if(dataframe$added[i]=="RESOLVED")
    {
      df <- paste(dataframe$added[i],"-",dataframe$added[i+1])
      dataframe$added[i+1] <- df
      dataframe <- dataframe[!(dataframe[i,])]
    }

  }

}
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Desired Result:

```
bug_id  bug_when            field       added
1141327 2015-03-09 16:21:30 Resolution  RESOLVED-DuPLICATE
1142623 2015-03-24 18:15:22 Resolution  RESOLVED-FIXED
1143179 2015-07-30 09:37:56 Resolution  RESOLVED-FIXED
```

Comment: Can you add your desired result of the data example you provided?

Comment: @PLapointe Desired result has been added

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr`. Basically, every time there was "RESOLVED" in t-1 of added, the added strings are concatenated with `paste`. When then use `filter` to keep only the field with "Resolution".

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(bug_id,bug_when)%>%
  mutate(added=ifelse(lag(added) =="RESOLVED" & !is.na(lag(added)),
                  paste(lag(added),(added),sep="-"),
                  added))%>%
  filter(field=="Resolution")

   bug_id            bug_when      field              added
    <int>               <chr>      <chr>              <chr>
1 1141327 2015-03-09 16:21:30 Resolution RESOLVED-DUPLICATE
2 1142623 2015-03-24 18:15:22 Resolution     RESOLVED-FIXED
3 1143179 2015-07-30 09:37:56 Resolution     RESOLVED-FIXED
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="bug_id  bug_when            field       added
1141327 '2015-03-09 16:21:30' Status      RESOLVED
1141327 '2015-03-09 16:21:30' Resolution  DUPLICATE
1142623 '2015-03-24 18:15:22' Status      RESOLVED
1142623 '2015-03-24 18:15:22' Resolution  FIXED
1143179 '2015-07-30 09:37:56' Status      RESOLVED
1143179 '2015-07-30 09:37:56' Resolution  FIXED",
                 header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to combine aggregate and paste, like this:

```
df <- read.table(text="bug_id  bug_when            field       added
1141327 '2015-03-09 16:21:30' Status      RESOLVED
1141327 '2015-03-09 16:21:30' Resolution  DUPLICATE
1142623 '2015-03-24 18:15:22' Status      RESOLVED
1142623 '2015-03-24 18:15:22' Resolution  FIXED
1143179 '2015-07-30 09:37:56' Status      RESOLVED
1143179 '2015-07-30 09:37:56' Resolution  FIXED",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE)

df2 <- aggregate(added ~ bug_id + bug_when, df,paste,collapse = "-")
df2$field <- "Resolution"

#    bug_id            bug_when              added      field
# 1 1141327 2015-03-09 16:21:30 RESOLVED-DUPLICATE Resolution
# 2 1142623 2015-03-24 18:15:22     RESOLVED-FIXED Resolution
# 3 1143179 2015-07-30 09:37:56     RESOLVED-FIXED Resolution
```